# Check if dataframe or specific string literal was passed to function

Tags: python, pandas, equality

I have a function that takes an argument which, among other things, could be either a dataframe or a string literal.

```
def func(could_be_df):
    if could_be_df=='optionA':data=stuffA()
    elif could_be_df=='optionB':data=stuffB()
    else:data=get_data(could_be_df)
```

When a dataframe is passed, this results in the "the truth value of an array with multiple elements is ambiguous" error.  I want df=='optionA' to resolve to False, since it obviously isn't the string literal I'm looking for.  How do I cleanly perform this check?

Stuff I've tried:

1. `if could_be_df is 'optionA'`.  Syntax warning, and sounds like it may not be safe to use "is".
2. `if isinstance(could_be_df,pd.DataFrame)`.  Could also be a series, array, list, etc.
3. `if isinstance(could_be_df,str)`.  Works, but gets messy since strings other than the literals should still go to get_data.  Also, not duck-typing.

Is there a clean, pythonic way to perform this check?

Comment: The method isinstance(could_be_df, pd.DataFrame) will only return True if "could_be_df" is an instance of the object pd.DataFrame. Thus, it returns False for any series, array, list.

Also, I think that you should not overdo the duck typing, and ask yourself if it is really necessary that "could_be_df" can be both, a string and a DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC and following your 3rd option, you could add a mapper and check for non literals :

```
def func(could_be_df):
    options = {"optionA": stuffA(), "optionB": stuffB()}

    if isinstance(could_be_df, str) and could_be_df in options:
        data = options[could_be_df]

    else: # i.e, DataFrames and non Literals
        data = get_data(could_be_df)

    # return data ?
```